# Cannot define category for undefined class UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift

What may be the reason of that issue?

This happens ONLY when I compile on real device. Everything is fine when I run with simulator.

Comment: I don't know *why* it's trying to build UIKit instead of just using it but I would try removing any UIKit references related to linking in your Build Settings or elsewhere, then add it back into your project as a framework.

Comment: For the framework target in the project navigator is uikit included?

Comment: @PranavKasetti for the GoogleToolboxForMac there is only one framework included: `Foundation`. See the image above

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Ok, if you add uikit as a framework for the Google framework target in settings, that should work

Comment: no, it still doesnt work;(

Comment: can you add your podfile?

Comment: Also, try some of the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163812/could-not-build-module-uikit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your UIKit.framework may be corrupted and you'll need to reinstall Xcode.