# Could not build module 'Foundation', 'UIKit, 'CoreFoundation' on Xcode 9.3 and Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode9.2, xcode9.3

Iam facing an issue from 4 days, but not able to resolved. The code which is working & succeeded fine in Xcode 9.2. but with same code on xcode 9.3 and xcode 9.4 facing the issues as "could not build module 'UIKit', 'Foundation' etc" as shown in attached screenshot. Could anyone face this type of issues? Please let me know the solution for this. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots please ?

Comment: it will occur in many scenarios : see this it helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163812/could-not-build-module-uikit

Comment: Did you wrote anything in Foundation framework ?

Comment: Check whether you've written something in Foundation Framework or clean build (CMD + OPTION + SHIFT + K) or update pods.

Comment: i already tried it and update the pods. not written anything in Foundation.framework.